# how to redraw canvas while the program is running In Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, desktop-application

I want the program to redraw the line depending on the ratio of the two values that the user enters

I tried this algorithm: 
I have two variable **pulse_length** and **distance_length**. The coordinates of [these two points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqtEe.png) depending on the ratio = (distance_length / (distance_length + pulse_length) * 540) + 40

When I call the on_text_validate event of the TextInput object, I write the entered values into variables and redraw the canvas. To redraw the canvas I used self.canvas.ask _update (), but that doesn't work

here is the simplified program code:

```py
# input variables
pulse_length = 499
distance_length = 999

# calculations
ratio = (distance_length / (distance_length + pulse_length) * 540) + 40

class Line(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Line, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            kg.Line(
                points=(
                    20, 350,
                    40, 350,
                    40, 240,
                    ratio, 240,
                    ratio, 350,
                    560, 350,
                    560, 240,
                    620, 240),

            # Other instructions ...

            Callback(self.update)
    def update(self, inst):
        ratio = (distance_length / (distance_length + pulse_length) * 540) + 40
        self.canvas.ask_update()

class TextInputGrid(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextInputGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.inputlayout = GridLayout(cols=1, size=(100, 30))
        self.inputlayout.textfield = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inputlayout.add_widget(self.inputlayout.textfield)

class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Drawn line widget
        self.add_widget(Line())

        # TextInput 1
        self.textinput1 = TextInputGrid()
        self.textinput1.inputlayout.textfield.bind(on_text_validate=self.enter_pulse)

        # TextInput 2
        self.textinput2 = TextInputGrid()
        self.textinput2.inputlayout.textfield.bind(on_text_validate=self.enter_distance)

        self.add_widget(self.textinput1.inputlayout)
        self.add_widget(self.textinput2.inputlayout)

    def enter_pulse(self, instance):
        global pulse_length
        pulse_length = int(self.textinput1.inputlayout.textfield.text)

    def enter_distance(self, instance):
        global distance_length
        distance_length = int(self.textinput2.inputlayout.textfield.text)


class GeneratorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyFloatLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GeneratorApp().run()
```

Maybe I don't know how ask_update() works? if so please explain how to redraw canvas. Or if algorithm incorrect, tell me how to implement such a program.

Comment: What is `kg` in your `Canvas` instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that `kg` is `Kivy.graphics`.

When you use `ratio` in your `Canvas` instructions, it uses the current value of `ratio`, and does not remember where that value came from. So, changing the current value of `ratio` will not change the `Line`. In order to update the `Line`, you need to redraw it. Here is a modification of your code that removes the old `Line` and draws a new version:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import kivy.graphics as kg

# input variables
pulse_length = 499
distance_length = 999

class Line(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ratio = (distance_length / (distance_length + pulse_length) * 540) + 40
        super(Line, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.line = kg.Line(
                points=(
                    20, 350,
                    40, 350,
                    40, 240,
                    ratio, 240,
                    ratio, 350,
                    560, 350,
                    560, 240,
                    620, 240))

            # Other instructions ...

            #Callback(self.update)
    def update(self):
        ratio = (distance_length / (distance_length + pulse_length) * 540) + 40
        self.canvas.remove(self.line)
        with self.canvas:
            self.line = kg.Line(
                points=(
                    20, 350,
                    40, 350,
                    40, 240,
                    ratio, 240,
                    ratio, 350,
                    560, 350,
                    560, 240,
                    620, 240))

class TextInputGrid(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextInputGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.inputlayout = GridLayout(cols=1, size=(100, 30))
        self.inputlayout.textfield = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inputlayout.add_widget(self.inputlayout.textfield)

class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Drawn line widget
        self.line = Line()
        self.add_widget(self.line)

        # TextInput 1
        self.textinput1 = TextInputGrid(pos=(0,0))
        self.textinput1.inputlayout.textfield.bind(on_text_validate=self.enter_pulse)

        # TextInput 2
        self.textinput2 = TextInputGrid(pos=(100,100))
        self.textinput2.inputlayout.textfield.bind(on_text_validate=self.enter_distance)

        self.add_widget(self.textinput1.inputlayout)
        self.add_widget(self.textinput2.inputlayout)

    def enter_pulse(self, instance):
        global pulse_length
        pulse_length = int(self.textinput1.inputlayout.textfield.text)
        self.line.update()

    def enter_distance(self, instance):
        global distance_length
        distance_length = int(self.textinput2.inputlayout.textfield.text)
        self.line.update()


class GeneratorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyFloatLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GeneratorApp().run()
```